# Why clicking an ImageButton in an Aspx page works only at second time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My goal is to display an image inside an ImageButton, after clicking on it. This works only when I click the Button second time. My markup:

```
   <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
              CodeBehind="Images.aspx.cs" Inherits="Monitas.Images" %>
     <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
     <style media="all">

       .Sheet {position: relative; left: 15%; top:15%; background: white; width: 800px; 
             height: 900px; border:3px solid #000;}

       .HeaderLogo {position: relative; background: yellow; width:240px; height:100px; left: 
             500px; top: 1px;  border:1px solid #000;}

        </style>

        </asp:Content>
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

        <asp:Panel ID="FOGLIO" class="Sheet" runat="server">

            <asp:ImageButton class="HeaderLogo" ID="HEADERLOGO" alternateText="Header Logo" 
                    runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" OnClick="OnImageHeaderClick" />

       </asp:Panel>

   </asp:Content>
```

And code behind: (OnImageHeaderClick seem to send a PostBack, but doesn't assign HeadImage
Only at second time I click, it assigns the variable)

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack) // Only second PostBack displays the HeadImage assigned by 
                OnImageHeaderClick
        {
            HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = HeadImage; // HeadImage is static Global
            Response.Write(HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl);
        }

    }
     // This seems not to be triggered a first time, despite it is declared in the Markup
    protected void OnImageHeaderClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        HeadImage = "Images/FooterLogo.png"; // assign image
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the way to avoid the second click. Actually it is enough to assign the HeaderLogo.ImageUrl during the OnImageHeaderClick, as shown in following code snippet:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = HeadImage;
        }

    }
    protected void OnImageHeaderClick(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        HEADERLOGO.ImageUrl = HeadImage = "Images/FooterLogo.png"; // use another image for experiment
    }
```

Comment: ah, so you fogot to use ispostback? Yes, that is quite much the first thing, and #1 thing that you MUST ALWAYS do for any thing like say loading up grids or whatever. If you don't place all such code in the first page load (postback = false)? You in fact cannot even built a working web page - ALWAYS do this and remember to do this.  All buttons, and ANY event triggered on a page will STILL always fire the page load event. So, if you going to build a web page with buttons or events on it? You cannot create a functional and working page if setup and loading of controls runs each time.